Rotate tick labels in ggplotly
I would like to have some rotated tick labels when using ggplotly. Unfortunately, after converting to ggplotly the labels are rotated back to normal. Here is some reproducible example:
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  guides(x =  guide_axis(angle = 90))
p


ggplotly(p)


Created on 2024-04-03 with reprex v2.0.2
So, I was wondering how can we rotate the labels when using ggplotly?

When writing the question I found the answer. We could use the layout function from plotly and specify the tickangle of the xaxis like this:
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
ggplotly(p) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(tickangle = -90))


Created on 2024-04-03 with reprex v2.0.2
